# Postfix smtp relay quota and configuration for Google Suite (Gmail)

Tags: postfix, g-suite, gmail

I'm trying to figure out a) what are the exact quota and also b) configuration for the SMTP relay service of Google App in postfix.

When I look at google documentation I can see that the relay host should be:

```
smtp-relay.gmail.com
```

So far I was using the following (which is working for years now):

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
```

So `smtp.gmail.com` instead of `smtp-relay.gmail.com`. Therefore what's the difference between the two? Am I currently not using the proper SMTP relay service? And does it has an impact in the [quota set by Google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en)?

My understanding is that I'm currently not using the correct SMTP relay service and that I'm limited by [different quota](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en). One element

Following that, I'm looking for a reference explaining how I can configure postfix to match the quota given by G Suite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally discovered that G-Suite has [a documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) article for this exact question.

> Depending on your requirements, the available options are:
>
> **G Suite SMTP relay service** — Send mail from your organization by authenticating  with the IP addresses. You can send messages to anyone inside or outside of your domain.
>
> **Gmail SMTP server** — Send mail to anyone inside or outside of your domain. This option requires you to authenticate with your Gmail or G Suite account and password.
>
> [...]

I'm currently using **Gmail SMTP server** which correspond to:

```
smtp.gmail.com
```

While **G Suite SMTP relay service** is using:

```
smtp-relay.gmail.com
```

And there is in fact a difference in the quota/sending limits depending of the choice. With `smtp-relay.gmail.com` the sending limits is of 10,000 emails per day and with `smtp.gmail.com` we are limited to 2,000 (For paid accounts).

---

**Update**:

With "Gmail SMTP server" I was used to see emails sent appearing in the sent folder of Gmail (Eg: from the web interface, you can see emails sent from postfix). However, using "G Suite SMTP relay service" will no longer save your emails in the sent folder.

Answer (score 0):

> With "Gmail SMTP server" I was used to see emails sent appearing in the sent folder of Gmail (Eg: from the web interface, you can see emails sent from postfix). However, using "G Suite SMTP relay service" will no longer save your emails in the sent folder.

Hi Maxime, apparently the behaviour you describe is by design, and it looks that it IS possible to have relayed emails (i.e., emails sent from your server through Google's relay host) saved. Check this out for a details: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491. Specifically, check the "Turn on comprehensive mail storage" section.